# Jolokia endpoint is not exposed through spring boot actuator in open shift

Tags: openshift, spring-boot-actuator, hawtio, jolokia, spring-boot-2

I have a `camel application which is running in spring boot 2` and camel routes are visualized through `hawtio`. And `all actuator endpoints are exposed including jolokia endpoint`

`this application is completely working in local` and
when I try to access actuator endpoints in local *`http://localhost:8080/actuator/`*, i could see below endpoint along with other 16 endpoints (such as health, info and so on)

```
"jolokia": {
"href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/jolokia",
"templated": false
}
```

I have `deployed the in same Openshift`, but when i try to `access actuator endpoints in Openshift`
i could see `only 16 endpoints without jolokia endpoint`

**Application start up logs in *`local`***

```
INFO : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
INFO : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3543 ms
INFO : Registered '/actuator/jolokia' to jolokia-actuator-endpoint
INFO : Initialising hawtio services
INFO : Configuration will be discovered via system properties
INFO : Welcome to Hawtio 2.10.0
INFO : Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS authentication disabled
INFO : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
INFO : Detected and using LURCacheFactory: camel-caffeine-lrucache
INFO : Exposing 17 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
```

**Application start up logs in *`Openshift`***

```
INFO : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
INFO : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3543 ms

INFO : Initialising hawtio services
INFO : Configuration will be discovered via system properties
INFO : Welcome to Hawtio 2.10.0
INFO : Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS authentication disabled
INFO : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
INFO : Detected and using LURCacheFactory: camel-caffeine-lrucache
INFO : Exposing 16 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
```

*`INFO : Registered '/actuator/jolokia' to jolokia-actuator-endpoint`* is missing in *`Openshift`* logs,
so clearly its not registered with *`spring boot actuator`*

Any idea *`why jolokia is not exposed via spring boot actuator`* ?

because of this `hawtio` is not able to access camel routes (JMX).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***`Issue is resolved
Solution : Disable the default OpenJDK8 jolokia in Openshift`***

***In Local***

Application is not running in Openshift / Docker as an image, running as normal spring boot application in tomcat so I didn't face this issue.

***In Openshift***

Application is running in openshift / Docker as an image instance.
The image is created with base openJDK 8 which has default jolokia enabled 
[Red hat openshift reference](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_middleware_for_openshift/3/html-single/red_hat_java_s2i_for_openshift/index#version_details)

I have disabled it by overriding it with `AB_JOLOKIA_OFF:true` in openshift environment variables.

*`or either`* if you are using `maven fabric8 plugin` in pom for building image then you can override jolokia properties it in pom itself (i haven't try it but its possible as per [documents](https://maven.fabric8.io/)).

[image: Environment variable]

[image: Default Jolokia With OpenJDK 8]